# How do I receive notification on foreground Activity changed

Tags: android, android-intent, service, android-activity, foreground

Is there a way to catch a system intent when foreground activity changes.

I looking to notify my service when the foreground Activity changes. 
(I know this can be done by busy-wait/pulling , this is no the solution I'm looking for).

Comment: I suppose your foreground activity is changing on button click using intent. Just start your service there simple...